# Frequency-dependent behaviour of opamps

Tags: operational-amplifier

Professor was teaching us the basics of opamps today, he went quite quickly over the frequency-dependency of opamps. 
He said the gain response to frequency was approximately a "first order response", can someone explain what it is and why this is true for opamps?

Comment: It simply means that GBW is approximately a constant.

Comment: Is your professor unable to explain this?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams thanks, he did mention GBW also but didn't make the link to first order response

Comment: @Andyaka I guess he did explain, but I tend to realise that I dont understand it when I'm revising haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The open-loop gain looks more-or-less like a large gain followed by a simple (first order) RC [low pass filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-pass_filter) (only one R and one C) with a pole typically at around 10Hz to a few kHz- fc.

So at much above fc, the gain falls off at 20dB/decade.

[image]

For a [real op-amp](http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ADA4841-1_4841-2.pdf) the gain might be 120dB at << fc and drop to 0dB at 10MHz.

[image]

Another way of saying this, as @Ignacio commented, is that the product of gain and bandwidth is constant (at much above fc, that is, for DC the gain does not go to infinity). This product is called GBW (gain multiplied by bandwidth).

You can see the deviation from -90° phase in the real op-amp phase response. Above a few MHz other stages in the op-amp begin to have an effect. The phase shift is still far from -180° when the gain drops below 1 (0dB), which means that this op-amp is unity-gain stable.

Comment: Why would the opamp be unstable if the phase hits -180°? I recall from circuit analysis that systems are unstable if their transfer function has poles/zeros that are in the positive half plane, can't see the connection between this and the -180° phase. Thanks for the explanation though!

Comment: Worst case (most feedback) is closed loop gain = 1. With 180°  phase shift and op-amp gain > 1  you have an oscillator, according to the Barkhausen criteria.

Answer (score 0):

The gain of any active circuit falls with frequency because the speed of the individual active devices is limited by various effects associated with charge storage at various nodes (modeled as parasitic capacitances).

An uncompensated opamp has a complex frequency (and phase) response as a result of all of the poles and zeros created by the individual transistors inside. In order to make circuit design using the opamp more tractable, most commercial devices have an internal compensation capacitor that creates a "[dominant pole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequency_compensation#Dominant-pole_compensation)" that effectively hides the effects of all the other poles and zeros.

Just to pull out a random example, take a look at figure 16 in the [LM358 datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm158-n.pdf). C<sub>C</sub> in the center of the diagram is what creates the dominant pole and sets the GBW product for this chip.

Comment: So the dominant pole capacitor just makes the gain start to drop at a lower frequency, to ensure that unpredictable effects of all other active components in the opamp dont occur? Correct me if I missed something